# AngularJs:-Add multiple conditions in ternary operations of ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ternary-operator, ng-class

I want to integrate multiple classes when the conditional expression in the *ng-class* attribute is true..

Below is the code I am trying, but not working:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-mouseover="hoverButton=true"  id="plain_text" ng-class="$state.current.name==='home' && 'hoverButton' ? 'tint,btn-white,panel_hover_font' : 'sd'" style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
```

I am not able to integrate `tint,btn-white,panel_hover_font` when the condition is true. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Remove quotes around `'hoverButton'`.

Comment: @Tushar I am not able to integrate the three css classes when condition is true

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it with ternary operators, but you can do it with simple conditions operators:

```
<span ng-class="{'a set of classes': condition.isTrue, 'another set of classes': condition.isFalse }"> </span>
```

I am using this in a real project and it is working. In your case it would give the following

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-mouseover="hoverButton=true" id="plain_text" ng-class="{ 'tint btn-white panel_hover_font': ($state.current.name==='home' && 'hoverButton'),  'sd': !($state.current.name==='home' && 'hoverButton') } " style="border: 1px solid; min-height: 300px;">
```

Comment: Done o/ But the next answers solved it with ternary operators  I think, just check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple CSS classes are separated with space, not comma:

```
ng-class="$state.current.name === 'home' && hoverButton ? 'tint btn-white panel_hover_font' : 'sd'"
```

Also, I assume `hoverButton` is a variable, not string `'hoverButton'`.

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mtr22ohr/)

You have to change `ng-class="'hoverButton' ? 'red, anotherclass, another' : 'white'"` to `ng-class="hoverButton ? 'red anotherclass another' : 'white'"`

I made up some css classes for testing purpose.